# How do you perform this mongo query? ( collisions of specific field )

Tags: mongodb

lets say i have a mongo db filled with people objects. Every person has address info ( street address, zip code and state etc) is there any way to find people who have the same address?

output like:

tom 
tim

adrian 
brian
margaret

where tim and tom share an address and adrian,brian and margret all 3 share an address

Answer (score 0):

Just use $aggregate with $addToSet.

**http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/**

sth like:

```
db.coll.aggregate(
                   [
                      { $group: {
                                  _id: "$address",
                                  names: { $addToSet : "$name" }
                                }
                      }
                   ]
)
```